# MVC Routing with wildcard

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes, wildcard

I am developing a website on  Asp MVC4

I have a link like that www.myhostname/category/{some arbitrary text}_ProductId

(e.g: www.myhostname.com/electronics/the-new-ipad_12345, in which 12345 is the ProductId that I need to extract)

Is the any way to register one route that give my directly the Id ?

I tried

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "productRoute",
            url: "{category}/*_{ProductId}",
            defaults: new { Controller = "Home", action = "Product" }

            );
```

But of course, it doesn't work

Note : as a work around, I used "{category}/{ProductLink}", to get the whole segment (e.g: the-new-ipad_12345) and extracted this ProductId on my action

Thanks & regards,

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using attribute based routing. You can add regex to [Route] attribute and parse the product id.

It is part of Web API 2 now. If you are using older version of Web API, you can add reference to - http://attributerouting.net/

The final solution will look something like..

```
[Route("electronics/{productId:int:regex(_([0-9]+))}")]
public ProductDto GetProduct(int productId)
{
    // ...
}
```